# Character encoding issues with migrating from MSSQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, encoding

We have an application called JIRA running on Windows using MSSQL and I need to migrate it to Linux/MySQL. The character encoding in the existing MSSQL db is latin1 but I need to use UTF-8 in MySQL.

I take an xml dump of the MSSQL data using a backup mechanism provided by the application. Run it through python filter to convert the encoding from latin1 to UTF-8. Here is the python code that was provided to me by my colleague.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import codecs, re

try:
highpoints = re.compile(u'[\U00010000-\U0010ffff]')
except re.error:
highpoints = re.compile(u'[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]')

#fin = codecs.open('unicodestuff.txt', encoding='utf-8', errors='replace')
 fin = codecs.open('entities.xml', encoding='latin1')
 fout = codecs.open('stripped.xml', encoding='utf-8', mode='w',       errors='replace')
 for line in fin:
 line = highpoints.sub(u'', line)
 fout.write(line)

fin.close()
fout.close()
```

I take the filtered xml dump and using a "restore" mechanism in the application, I restore the data. However, after restoring the data, I spot checked few records on the MySQL side and I see some weird characters and I am assuming these are related to character encoding. For example,

On the MSSQL side, the text string is

““Number of debits exceeds maximum of 0”

“2-Restrict All Credits”

Default ของประเภทบัญชีถูกต้อง แต่เลขบัญชีไม่ถูกต้อง

Branch : 724 มาบุญครอง

whereas on the MYSQL side, the corresponding text appears as

â??â??Number of debits exceeds maximum of 0â?

â??2-Restrict All Creditsâ?

Default à¸à¸­à¸à¸à¸£à¸°à¹à¸ à¸à¸à¸±à¸à¸à¸µà¸à¸¹à¸à¸à¹à¸­à¸ à¹à¸à¹à¹à¸¥à¸à¸à¸±à¸à¸à¸µà¹à¸¡à¹à¸à¸¹à¸à¸à¹à¸­à¸

Branch : 724 à¸¡à¸²à¸à¸¸à¸à¸à¸£à¸­à¸

Can you please provide me some ideas to fix these character encoding issues? Kindly let me know if additional information is required.

Thanks
Sam

Comment: One thing to watch out for is that Windows likes to lie when it says it's using Latin1... but you've got bigger problems than that.  Once you solve your main issue, you might still have a few bad chars.  Anyway, one major issue is that the alphabet on the source side is definitely not latin1.  Those characters cannot be represented in latin1.  What is actually in the XML?

Comment: @paul-kienitz The source side encoding is cp1252 and I thought that it is synonymous to latin1. Apologize if I misled. The XML contains metadata about the environment from where it is being exported and all the records in the source database apart from some application specific data like the plugins that were being used.

Comment: The important question is: does the XML contain characters such as มาบุญครอง?  Such characters do not exist in CP 1252 or Latin1, so if they're present, the actual encoding in your XML is not what you think it is.

If they're not present, then your problem is not one of translating the XML, but of exporting it.  You will have to export in some format other than Latin1.  You'd probably better do that anyway, because if you retain the fake Latin1 encoding, what you've got is some kind of adhoc bastardized pretend encoding which isn't legitimately valid.  You shouldn't base transactions on that.

Comment: By the way, the difference between CP1252 and Latin1 is that the former contains 27 extra characters which are nonstandard.  These include things like dagger, per-mil, ellipsis, TM, bullet, em- and en-dashes, open and close quotes, and the Euro sign.  You have to watch out for these any time you work with "Latin-1" in Windows.  Because from what I've seen, Windows is incapable of using the true Latin1 set without the extensions.

Comment: If the XML file does contain those non-latin letters, you might need to do a hex dump of it to determine what encoding it's really using.  Since it's Microsoft, the most likely answer might be UTF-16, but it might be an old code page like 874, or already in UTF-8.

Comment: @paul-kienitz   Yes, I have opened the xml file in vi and here is the corresponding text.  "summary="Defect_22039: MF - Redemption ค่า Default ของประเภทบัญชีถูกต้อง แต่เลขบัญชีไม่ถูกต้อง" 
  Branch : 724 มาบุญครอง^M


Detail : ค่า Default ของประเภทบัญชีถูกต้อง แต่เลขบัญชีไม่ถูกต้อง 2261193593 ต้องเป็น 5311291492 ตามระบบ MF

Answer (score 0):

Clearly your XML file does not actually use the Latin-1 character set.  You've shown that text such as "ของประเภทบัญชีถูกต้อง แต่เลขบัญชีไม่ถูกต้อง" is present in it.  The Latin-1 character set does what it says on the label: it represents letters from Latin alphabets.  Those letters do not exist in it.  If the headers in your XML file claim that it's in Latin-1, then those headers are untrue and the XML is, strictly speaking, not valid.  But it might still be usable.

Now the problem is, what character encoding is that XML file actually using?  To find out, you may have to examine the XML file in hexadecimal.  There are three main possibilities: (1) it's using an old codepage such as 874 which contains these characters; (2) it's using UTF-16; (3) it's using UTF-8.

If you examine in hexadecimal a section of the XML which contains some of this non-latin text, and some of the latin letters nearby, here's what you might see.  If it's in a codepage such as 874, each latin letter will be one byte with a value from 32 to 7F, and each nonlatin letter will be one (or possibly two?) bytes with values of 80 to FF.  If it's in UTF-16, each latin letter will be two bytes, one from 32 to 7F and the other being always 00, and the nonlatin letters will be two bytes with neither being 00.  If it's in UTF-8, the latin letters will be one byte from 32 to 7F, and the nonlatin letters will be (probably) three bytes, all being from 80 to FF.

There may be an alternative to examining hexadecimal.  Some text editor programs can save text files in your choice of encoding formats.  TextPad 7, for instance, can save as ANSI, DOS, UTF-8, Unicode, or Unicode (big-endian).  The latter two options are actually UTF-16.  Try loading the XML into such a program, and saving copies of it as UTF-8 and as Unicode.  One of these copies should be the same size as the original (plus or minus two or three bytes), and the other will be a different size.  Whichever matches the size is probably the correct format.  If both differ, then you've got something weird.

Anyway, if you save a version as UTF-8 and then are able to open it and see your data intact, you should then be able to import that without using a Python translator.

Comment: Thank you so much Paul for the guidance which helped us nail it. Since the character encoding was set to cp1252 on the production system, we all assumed that the xml dump's encoding is also cp1252/latin1. The XML dump comes over as a compressed archive and the importing application extracts and processes the file. Since you mentioned that those characters can't be of cp1252 or latin1, I had a suspicion about the encoding of the XML dump. So I extracted the xml dump and in the first line it said encoding = utf-8. With little clean up and no python filtering, import is successful.